MP3 Album Art Tagging with Mutagen and eyed3 Not Displayed on Some Media Players
I'm embedding album art into MP3 files using the eyeD3 library in Python. The album art is successfully embedded and displays correctly in some music players (e.g., Pot Player, Hash music player and others), but it doesn't show up in others, like Samsung Music ,these are 3 playersTube Music.
here is the code
# Load the MP3 file
audiofile = eyed3.load('path/to/temp_audio.mp3')
if audiofile.tag is None:
    audiofile.initTag()

# Read the album art image
with open('C:/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb') as albumart:
    image_data = albumart.read()

# Set the track title
audiofile.tag.title = "Track Title"

# Embed the image as the front cover
audiofile.tag.images.set(
    ImageFrame.FRONT_COVER,   # Front cover image type
    image_data,               # Image data
    'image/jpeg'              # MIME type for JPEG image
)

# Save the MP3 file with tags (using ID3v2.3)
audiofile.tag.save(version=eyed3.id3.ID3_V2_3)

then :audiofile.tag.save(version=eyed3.id3.ID3_V2_4)
and also tried mutagen
i tried the low resolutions too

Not all players can read images in all formats... especially not in MP3 where there are a half dozen ways to shove data into the file that was never meant to have that extra data in the first place.

All Audio downloader with meta data output an mp3 that is capable of displaying its album art on all audio players that support it,  why is mine not working on some, Just wanna know the pro way it's done
